# How can I create this column chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2011

Well, I'm trying to create a column chart from this simple piece of data and I don't quite understand how the the chart tool is selecting the data and axises.

Here is the data:
[http://imgur.com/8goze5m](https://imgur.com/8goze5m)

And here is the kind of chart I want to create:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUBP9.jpg

With number of respondents on the y-axis, number of hours on the x-axis and the data in the column chart split between Dublin and outside Dublin.

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a regular chart straight away, because you have not created a summary.  A bar chart would expect a field of your count/bar-height...

You can, however, create the summary and the chart at the same time by creating a pivot-chart. My version is 2010, but should be very similar:

1. Highlight your table
2. Choose `Insert` -> Arrow under `Pivot Table` to choose `Pivot Chart`
3. Choose `OK` to create a new sheet for the Pivot Table/Chart
4. In the `Field List` set:

   a.  `Legend Fields (Series)` = Area

   b    `Axis Fields (Categories)` = Avg Facebook Hours

   c.   `Values` = Count of Gender (or any other unused field)

Note--Pivot Charts are more limited than normal charts.  If you want full chart formatting functionality, create a Pivot Table, copy the results into a new "static" table, and then chart.

Comment: Hi Madball73, sorry for not getting back to you. Cheers for the answer, a Pivot Chart as you suggested was how I did it in the end. Problem was I was using Excel for Mac 2011 which doesn't come with the Pivot Chart feature so once I realised that I just had to move it to Windows and it was fairly simple from there.

Answer (score 0):

First - Your current column for the hours of usage is a string as per the image, so that wouldn't work. So I suppose you will need another column which has the number of hours of usage, or you can also do two columns with the range (start-end).

After adding the chart, you will be able to edit the data series, the axis, the labels.

Can you provide what range are you choosing as data for the X-Axis & what range for the Y-Axis - and how does the graph appear currently?